# BERT embeddings + LSTM for NER

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I am working with the Conll-2003 dataset for Named Entity Recognition. What I want to do is to use the BERT embeddings as an input to a simple LSTM. Here's the code:

```
class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.params = params

        self.embedding = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-large-cased")
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-cased")

        for param in self.embedding.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False                 

        params.max_sen_len += 2     # "[CLS]", "[SEP]"
        params.embedding_dim = params.bert_dim

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(params.embedding_dim, params.hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(params.hidden_dim, params.num_of_tags)


    def forward(self, sentences, labels):
        tokenized_sentences = []
        tokenized_sen = []
        tokenized_word = []
        
        tokenized_labels = []
        tokenized_sen_labels = []
        idx = -1
        is_first = True

        for sen, lab in zip(sentences, labels):
            if sen[0] != "[CLS]":
                sen.insert(0, "[CLS]")
                sen.append("[SEP]")
                lab.insert(0, self.params.pad_tag_num)
                lab.append(self.params.pad_tag_num)
            idx = -1
            for word in sen:
                idx += 1
                tokenized_word = self.tokenizer.tokenize(word)

                is_first = True
                for token in tokenized_word:
                    tokenized_sen.append(token)
                    if is_first:
                        tokenized_sen_labels.append(lab[idx])
                        is_first = False
                    else:
                        tokenized_sen_labels.append(-1)

            tokenized_sentences.append(tokenized_sen)
            tokenized_labels.append(tokenized_sen_labels)
            tokenized_sen = []
            tokenized_sen_labels = []

        labels = tokenized_labels
        labels = pad_sequences([[l for l in lab] for lab in labels],
            maxlen=self.params.max_sen_len, value=self.params.pad_tag_num, padding="post",  
            dtype="long", truncating="post")

        mask = (labels >= 0)
        mask = torch.FloatTensor(mask)
        if self.params.cuda:
            mask = mask.cuda()

        inputs = pad_sequences([self.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(sen) for sen in tokenized_sentences],
                        maxlen=self.params.max_sen_len, dtype="long", truncating="post", padding="post")

        inputs = torch.LongTensor(inputs)
        if self.params.cuda:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()

        x = self.embedding(inputs, attention_mask = mask)[0]

        x, _ = self.lstm(x)
        x = x.contiguous()
        x = x.view(-1, x.shape[2])
        x = self.fc(x)

        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1), labels


self.params.pad_tag_num = -1
```

I use only the first wordpiece of each tokenized word, the rest is set to -1.

My first question is: am I doing it the right way? I did the same with ELMo and GloVe embeddings and the worst accuracy I obtain for BERT (haven't checked the F1 score).

The second question is: Should I somehow care about the entity labels? I mean there are labels like B-PER and I-PER. This is the same type of an enity. Should I somehow treat it as one entity and classify the whole? Or should I classify each word?